# How does salicylic acid work on acne?

Tags: skin

There are claims that salicylic acid has an effect on acne. I have done preliminary research and found multiple sources saying:

- "Salicylic acid [can] help prevent future breakouts." - https://www.healthline.com/health/skin/salicylic-acid-for-acne
- "Salicylic acid penetrates into your skin and works to dissolve the dead skin cells clogging your pores." - https://www.healthline.com/health/skin/salicylic-acid-for-acne
- "Salicylic Acid works by opening the pores and killing the bacteria inside." - https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/tuqt2/how_do_things_like_salicylic_acid_and_topical/
- Pointing out that salicylic acid is used to treat acne, but no explanation as to how. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_uses_of_salicylic_acid
- "Salicylic acid modulates COX2 gene expression to decrease the formation of pro-inflammatory prostaglandins. Salicylate may competitively inhibit prostaglandin formation. Salicylate's antirheumatic (nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory) actions are a result of its analgesic and anti-inflammatory mechanisms. Salicylic acid works by causing the cells of the epidermis to slough off more readily, preventing pores from clogging up, and allowing room for new cell growth. Salicylic acid inhibits the oxidation of uridine-5-diphosphoglucose (UDPG) competitively with nicotinamide adenosine dinucleotide (NAD) and noncompetitively with UDPG. It also competitively inhibits the transferring of glucuronyl group of uridine-5-phosphoglucuronic acid (UDPGA) to the phenolic acceptor.", again, with no source. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicylic_acid
- "Because BHAs [specifically salicylic acid] are oil soluble, they’ll be able to penetrate deep into the sebum filling up your pores, loosening the gunk to make it easier to remove" - https://fiftyshadesofsnail.com/2015/03/28/how-to-shrink-pores-temporarily-plus-3-pore-myths/
- "Salicylic acid dissolves well in vegetable oils." - https://chemistscorner.com/cosmeticsciencetalk/discussion/2514/how-to-dissolve-salicylic-acid-or-aha-acid-in-oil
- "Salicylic acid helps ... by dissolving the type of skin debris that clogs pores and causes acne" - https://www.huffpost.com/entry/heres-exactly-what-salicylic-acid-does-to-your-skin_b_578cff25e4b07cc1115aa329

Therefore, the sum of claims add up to that salicylic acid

1. Penetrates skin.
2. Dissolves dead skin and skin debris.
3. Separates skin.
4. Opens pores.
5. Reduces inflammation.

If I suppose the anti-inflammatory properties of salicylic acid is well-documented by virtue of being similar to acetylsalicylic acid, then 5) can be intuitive. My remaining questions are as follows.

1. **How** does salicylic acid penetrate skin? Which part of the skin? What does it do there? How does it penetrate skin better than other amphiphilic molecules?
2. **How** does an acid dissolve dead skin and skin debris? How much acid, at what concentration, at what temperature, and for how long?
3. Through what mechanism does salicylic acid "open pores"? Additionally, if opening pores is one of its selling points, is it not true that ordinary soap also removes dirt from pores?

Comment: Most of the claims above are from unreliable sources. https://scholar.google.com/ might be a better place to search. Since this is a medical topic, https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ would also be a good choice. Apart from these, you could look up the references in the Wikipedia article.